# assign 2D array to another 2D array

Tags: vb.net

I am working in this project where I have to compare the value of an array with itself so I have used 2 2D arrays having the same size and values where I used one for comparing while making changes to the other the problem is that when I make changes to one the other also changes.

is there any way I can assign the value of any 2D arrays without having them changing together.

what I have used is the simple vb.net assignment:
x=y and it works fine only for that one issue.
I haven't completed the code yet that's what I have for now.

```
xgame = game

For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To n - 1
        If (j = 0 And i = 0) Then
            If xgame(i, j + 1) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If xgame(i + 1, j) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If xgame(i + 1, j + 1) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If count <= 1 Then
                game(i, j) = "-"
            End If
        ElseIf (i = 0 And ((j > 0) Or (j < n - 1))) Then
            count = 0
            If xgame(i, j - 1) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If xgame(i, j + 1) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If xgame(i + 1, j - 1) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If xgame(i + 1, j) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If xgame(i + 1, j + 1) = "1" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If (count < 2 Or count > 3) Then
                game(i, j) = "-"
            ElseIf (count = 3) Then
                game(i, j) = "1"
            End If
        ElseIf (i = 0 And j = n - 1) Then
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code examples?

Comment: so i'm working on this game it's called the game of life what i have done is that i assigned the values then worked on changing one array but then both of them changed

Comment: If you're finding that changing one array causes the other to change too then it is almost certain that you only actually have one array. Consider this. Let's say that you live in a house. That house is your house. I move in with you. That house is now my house too. If I burn down my house, can you keep happily living in yours? Of course not, because there's only one house. An array is an object like a house. If you have an array variable and you assign it to another variable you do NOT create another array. You simply have two variables referring to the same object. You need to create a copy.

Comment: To create a copy, you must first create a new array object of the same size and then copy each element from the original. You would generally use nested `For` loops to access each element of a 2D array.

Comment: OK i get it now thank you i will try to create a copy instead of assigning

Comment: it works correctly now.